# CAN connect to Docker service on localhost. CANNOT connect to Docker service on LAN IP Address

Tags: docker, networking

I have a Docker service running on an Ubuntu 19.04 server, which lives on my LAN.

The service in question exposes a SOCKS5 proxy on port `1080`.

When I run the following commands from the server they work:

```
~$ curl --proxy socks5://127.0.0.1:1080 ipinfo.io
{
  "ip": "xx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
  "city": "Phoenix",
  "region": "Arizona",
  "country": "US",
  ...
}
```

```
~$ docker container inspect my-docker-service | grep IPAddress
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "IPAddress": "",
                    "IPAddress": "172.19.0.8",

~$ curl --proxy socks5://172.19.0.8:1080 ipinfo.io
{
  "ip": "xx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
  "city": "Phoenix",
  "region": "Arizona",
  "country": "US",
  ...
}
```

But when I run this one from the server, it doesn't:

```
~$ ip a
...
3: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    ...
    inet 192.168.1.95/24
    ...

~$ curl --proxy socks5://192.168.1.95:1080 ipinfo.io
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.1.95 port 1080: Connection timed out
```

My `docker-compose.yml` looks like:

```
  my-docker-service:
    privileged: true
    image: ohpe/socks-my-vpn
    container_name: my-docker-service
    devices:
      - /dev/net/tun
    cap_add:
      - net_admin
    tty: true
    sysctls:
      net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6: 0
    environment:
      - PROXY_PORT=1080
    volumes:
      - /path/to/configs/my-docker-service:/vpn:ro
    ports:
      - 1080:1080
    dns:
      - 1.1.1.1
    restart: unless-stopped
```

I've disabled `ufw`, and also using nmap on another LAN device gives me:

```
λ nmap -p 1080 192.168.1.95
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at xxx
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.95
Host is up (0.0020s latency).

PORT     STATE    SERVICE
1080/tcp filtered socks
MAC Address: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (xxx)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 5.53 seconds
```

How can I make this proxy service available to other devices on my LAN?

Comment: That setup definitely sounds like there’s still a firewalling issue.  Your `docker-compose.yml` file looks correct, and you can access the service from the host via the published port.  (The `docker inspect` path is a distraction.) Stack Overflow tends to focus a little more on code-oriented problems.

Comment: Is there a way I can try to track down where/if there's a firewall interfering somewhere?